# How do I create a curved line between two points in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to curve the space between the beginning and end points of a line. I have tried using interpolate however this just breaks the graph. Does anyone have any other methods of achieving this?

```
var lines = linesContainer.selectAll("line.bot")
  .data(lineData);

lines.exit().remove();

lines
  .enter()
  .append("line")
     .attr("fill", "none")
     .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
     .attr("stroke-width", "6");

lines
  .attr("class", function (d) {
     var isPositive = function (o) {
       if (o.y2 === 0) {
         return Math.sign(o.y1) >= 0;
       }
       return Math.sign(o.y2) >= 0;
     }

     if (isPositive(d)) {
       return "s-g3 bot";
     }
     return "s-r2 bot";
  })
  .attr('x1', function (d) {
     return x(d.x1);
  })
  .attr('y1', function (d) {
     return y(d.y1);
  })
  .attr('x2', function (d) {
     return x(d.x2);
  })
  .attr('y2', function (d) {
     return y(d.y2);
  });
```

Comment: "curve the space" is a little vague - what did you have in mind?  "tried using interpolate however this just breaks the graph" - what does that mean?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.  Do you just want curved lines instead of straight?

Comment: latest version of D3 comes with d3.link which be worth checking out https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#linkVertical or https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#linkHorizontal, and coming back if this isn't what you are after